# How to plot all the rows in each column of a pandas df to a separate bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm trying to plot for each columns of the df_new on a separate bar plot, however it keeps on giving me all of the plots on each chart. as I have 33 columns, my solution should be 33 bar plots showing row 1 and rows 2 corresponding to each column.

[image: See this screenshot]

Update, to make it clearer, image shows (shown in excel) how each plot would look, so the next one would be 'r(0,0)' and so on

[image: another screenshot]

Comment: You need to create subplots first, here is [demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: `df.T.plot.bar(subplots=True)`

Comment: @QuangHoang that doesn't work, as it only gives two plots. im looking to have a plot for each coloums (so 33). each plot would contain  2 bars representing the two data points in that column

Comment: Then forget the `T`: `df.plot.bar(subplots=True)`. You can add an option `layout=(3,4)` depending how you want your subplots be arranged.

Comment: sorry, what is the layout referring to? I tried df_new.plot.bar(subplots=True,layout=(1,33)), but I only get the below output repeated 33 times ?array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x00000233A680EF88>,

Comment: I dont think subplots are required as its only one axis.